# mysql ssl enable без перезапуска

Tags: mysql, linux, openssl

Приветствую всех. Подскажите пожалуйста с mysql.

```
mysql> show variables like '%ssl%';
+---------------+-------------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                               |
+---------------+-------------------------------------+
| have_openssl  | DISABLED                            |
| have_ssl      | DISABLED                            |
```

Как сделать включение ssl без рестарта mysql.
Пробовал так

```
mysql> SET @@GLOBAL.have_ssl=1;
ERROR 1238 (HY000): Variable 'have_ssl' is a read only variable

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.37, for debian-linux-gnu
```

Comment: без изменения конфигурации и перезапуска — никак.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

без изменения конфигурации с последующим перезапуском — насколько мне известно — никак.